# ILMerge in VS2013 post build activity

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, ilmerge

I have 2 questions. Please find them below.

1. How to remove .pdb files while doing ILMerge in post-build activity
2. How to merge the managed and unmanaged dll into post build activity using IL merge

Answer (score 1):

If you've integrated [ILMerge using MsBuild from the MsBuildCommunityTasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Source/MSBuild.Community.Tasks/ILMerge/ILMerge.cs), then simply calling a `<delete />` task after it will help you get rid of the PDB files, from which you can generate the names based on the inputs for ILMerge.

It's not possible to merge Managed and Unmanaged assemblies using ILMerge, since unmanaged assemblies are, by definition, not made up of Intermediate Language. There are other tricks, such as embedding these as resources or using more advanced linking tools, but it's certainly not possible with just ILMerge.